# Compilation failure Java source

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

```
error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
```

However when I run java -version and javac -version I get:

```
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

```
javac 1.7.0_45
```

Which source is it talking about?
I am trying to compile a maven project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you have java 1.7 on your machine it does not mean that Maven is set to compile using that version. Check your .pom file for errors.

It should look something like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.7</source>
      <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, now the error is gone!

Answer (score 2):

Which source class fails to compile with this error?  That is thte one which has a generic.

Most likely you have forgotten to set a source level and you actually want to compile your code as Java 6 or 7.

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
```